# how to set height responsively in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap for creating div. Please look at the below fiddle,

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ros9xv43/2/)

- )  I have 4 divs in my page. two on top and two on bottom. My 4 cards div's height should be same. It could not change.
- )  In the last div inside it may be one or two or three div might come. It will maximum three or less than 3 divs.
- ) If only one div the height should be 100% same as the first 3 divs.
- ) In the last card if two divs are there means, it should conver as 50% and 50% each and scroll should come. If three divs are there means, (100% / 3) should come.
- )  Only the last card inside how many divs will come, based on that the height should automatically change.

Can anyone please help me how can I achieve this.

I am using angularjs for my frontend. I have a flag "totalcount". So I will get nested divs count. How can I set height.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.row{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}
#responseData{
  display:inline-block;width:40%;border:1px solid red;padding:3px;
}
#responseDataa{
  display:inline-block;width:40%;height:45px;border:1px solid red;padding:3px;overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-12'>
          <div id="responseData">
          Why the heck do the divs stack on top of each other when this line gets really long?  I would think they would be side by side because the display property of the div is set to inline block
          </div>
          <div id="responseData">
          Why the heck do the divs stack on top of each other when this line gets really long?  I would think they would be side by side because the display property of the div is set to inline block
          </div>
           <div id="responseData">
          Why the heck do the divs stack on top of each other when this line gets really long?  I would think they would be side by side because the display property of the div is set to inline block
          </div>
          
           <div id="responseDataa">
          Why the heck do the divs stack on top of each other when this line gets really long?  I would think they would be side by side because the display property of the div is set to inline block
          </div>
           <div id="responseDataa">
          Why the heck do the divs stack on top of each other when this line gets really long?  I would think they would be side by side because the display property of the div is set to inline block
          </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use same id for multiple HTML elements

Comment: For me data will come from API. It is dynamic.

Comment: In your css you set `width: 40%` thus only two divs fit in one row regardless of the length of the text.

Comment: why are you using Bootstrap 3 if the question is tagged Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
height: -webkit-fill-available;
```

[image]